# How to join multiple tables using JPA annotation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm able to join two tables to create `CollectionTable`. (I use hibernate implemetnation)

```
@CollectionTable(name = "table_user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
```

How can I join three tables?

I have the following tables: table_user, table_role, table_user_role

So I need to represent the triple join in a `@CollectionTable`

```
table_user JOIN table_user_role ON user_id 
table_role JOIN table_user_role ON role_id
```

Comment: JPA annotations don't "join" anything; they reflect relationships between classes. Where are the classes so that people can comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @SecondaryTable(name="table2") to map another table to same entity.